# fields of type ManyToManyField do not save data when sending a request, DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Basically I do something like 'Archive of Our Own' and I don't have work saved or saved but ManyToMany field data is not saved

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
    serializer = FanficSerializerCreate(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response({'fanfic': serializer.data}, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

models.py

```
class Fanfic(models.Model):
...
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  fandoms = models.ManyToManyField(Fandom)
  pairings = models.ManyToManyField(Pairing)
  characters = models.ManyToManyField(Hero)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
....
```

serializer.py

```
class FanficSerializerCreate(ModelSerializer):

  fandoms = FandomSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  pairings = PairingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  characters = HeroSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Fanfic
    fields = ['id', 'user', 'title', 'fandoms', 'pairings', 'characters', 'translate', 'categories', 'end', 'relationships', 'tags', 'description', 'note', 'i_write_for', 'created', 'updated']
```

I think the problem is in the serializer for another section, for example, adding a character with the same view code, but without the manytomanyfield fields in the models works fine

when I write this in the serializers.py

```
fandoms = FandomSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  pairings = PairingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  characters = HeroSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

displays

```
{
   "fanfic": {
      "id": 4,
      "user": 3,
      "title": "Claimed",
      "fandoms": [],
      "pairings": [],
      "characters": [],
      "translate": "NO",
      "categories": "M",
      "end": "ENDED",
      "relationships": "M/M",
      "tags": [],
      "description": "",
      "i_write_for": "...",
      "created": "2022-11-14T13:46:44.425693Z",
      "updated": "2022-11-14T13:46:44.425693Z"
   }
}
```

id is just not added to the fields

when I write this in the serializers.py

```
fandoms = FandomSerializer(many=True)
  pairings = PairingSerializer(many=True)
  characters = HeroSerializer(many=True)
  tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
```

in postman

```
{
   "message": {
      "fandoms": [
         "This field is required."
      ],
      "pairings": [
         "This field is required."
      ],
      "characters": [
         "This field is required."
      ],
      "tags": [
         "This field is required."
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make nested serializers' fields as unrequired by `required=False` to that field:

```py
class FanficSerializerCreate(ModelSerializer):

  fandoms = FandomSerializer(many=True, required=False)
  ...

  class Meta:
    model = Fanfic
    ...
```

Also, you can have it for different fields in the `Meta` class:

```py
class FanficSerializerCreate(ModelSerializer):

  fandoms = FandomSerializer(many=True)
  ...

  class Meta:
    model = Fanfic
    extra_kwargs = {
        'fandoms': {'required': False}
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Reference:
(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required)